# Como evitar muitas chamadas "use" para resolução de namespaces

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou refatorando um pequeno sistema em mvc que utilizava o padrão `classmap` para o `psr-4`, e fui "obrigado" a usar vários "use" dentro de cada controller para resolver os namespaces.

Exemplo de como era o controller com classmap:

```
use Particle\Filter\Filter; //biblioteca de filtro
use Rakit\Validation\Validator; // biblioteca de validacao de dados

class Teste extends Controller {

    function index () {

        $config = jsonConfig::get('dbconfig'); //classe qualquer

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($config);

    }
}
```

Uso do mesmo controller com o psr-4:

```
namespace App\controllers;

use App\core\Controller;
use App\models\config\jsonConfig;
use Particle\Filter\Filter;
use Rakit\Validation\Validator;

class Teste extends Controller {


    function index () {

        $config = jsonConfig::get('dbconfig');

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($config);

    }
}
```

Esse é só um exemplo, eu tenho que fazer isso em diversos controllers, models etc, existe alguma boa prática para automatizar isso, criando algo como uma factory para controllers, para models etc, que já resolva os namespaces genéricos de cada "parte" do sistema.

Atualização:

Também percebi que agora preciso usar uma barra invertida na chamada de classes nativas, ex: `new PDO` virou `new \PDO`

Comment: Essa ```\``` da observação é para "sair" do namespace atual. E qual o problema de vários `use`?

Comment: Não parece algo prático, ter que ficar fazendo a mão N ´use´s, não vejo isso nos frameworks

Comment: Que frameworks? Todos que conheço e que usam o composer precisam usar o namespace. Possível é mas acho inviável. Um alternativa é criar apelidos para a classe no composer, não retira, mas diminui o tamanho

Comment: Sim, sei que usam, quis dizer essa lista longa de use, é algo mais compacto

Comment: Em essência é fazer códigos menos complexos. PHP é ótimo para fazer códigos simples, mas por alguma razão as pessoas começaram fazer coisas mais complexas do que o necessário. Acho que é porque está moda. As pessoas não se perguntam que benefícios ela está tendo em complicar tanto o código. O que não é prático é fazer MVC em códios simples. MVC foi criado para aplicações extramente complexas.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, não acho que tenha nada "complexo" aí, basicamente o principio da responsabilidade única, por isso tem muitos USE

Comment: ou é melhor continuar com o classmap?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente não usar o `use` e colocar o namespace completo ao invocar funções, criar instâncias, etc:

```
namespace App\controllers;

class Teste extends Controller {

    function index () {

        $config = App\models\config\jsonConfig::get('dbconfig');

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($config);

    }
}
```

Porém, como pode ver, o namespace pode ser um pouco grande, e repeti-lo várias vezes não é muito interessante, em alguns casos pode até ser melhor, mas poucos

Outra opção, que pode ser combinada com a anterior, é você criar apelidos, por exmplo, uma classe que fica nesse namespace:

```
Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux
```

poderi ser chamada através de:

```
Alias\Qux
```

Assim, você pode chamar da forma original (longa) e da nova (curta), com uma configuração semelhante a:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Alias\\": "./Foo/Bar/Baz"
        }
    }
}
```

Mas o mais importante é **Por que fazer diferente?** Na maioria das linguagens você tem algum tipo de importação, que é semelhante aos namespaces do PHP, por exemplo, uma classe de controle de um CRUD simples com o ecossistema Spring começa assim:

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import com.example.model.MyModel;
import com.example.repository.MyRepository;
```

A estrutura é bem semelhante, não?

Namespaces são bons, ajudam a organizar o código de terceiros, dificulta problemas com classes e nomes de arquivos iguais